# Use table key inside same (anonymous) table

Tags: lua, computercraft

I want to use a key insde an anonymous table from within that same table, like so:

```
loadstring( [[return {
  a = "One",
  b = a.." two"
}]] )
```

From my perspective, this *should* return the following table:

```
{ a = "One", b = "One two" }
```

However, it just returns `nil`.
**Is this possible to do, and how?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623338/1442917) said, you can't reference a key in a table that is being constructed, but you can use a variable to hold the value you want to reference several times:

```
local a = "One"
local t = { a = a, b = a.." two" }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. At the point you are using `a` the table has not been constructed. Lua looks for a global variable `a`, which is why you get `nil`.

If you want to refer to keys in a table they must be defined first.

```
local t = { a = 'One' }
t.b = t.a..' two'
```